# How to do certain indentations

Tags: macros, indentation

I tried searching for an answer, but franly I'm so new to LaTeX that I don't even know what I'm searching for, so I'll explain what I'm trying to find below.

I would like to have this as one of my pages.

```
Published by:     Name.
                  Name.
                  Name.
```

But when I attempt to do this in LaTeX, I get this.

```
Published by:    Name.
                  Name.
                  Name.
```

Which I got by doing doing this.

```
Published by:\tab\textbf{Name.\\}
\tab\tab\tab\tab\tab\textbf{Name.\\}
\tab\tab\tab\tab\tab\textbf{Name.\\}
```

with `\tab` being

```
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
```

This is obviously an extremely crude way of doing it, so I was wondering if anybody had a more elegant solution.

EDIT: I thought I would continue asking my questions here, as it sort of falls under the same category.

What if I want something like this.

```
Published by:    Name.
                 Name.
                 Name.

Title:           Title, Subtitle.
Author:          Author.

If you request any further info, contact.

                 Name.
                 Name.
```

So that all of the information is on the same indentation. Would it be smart to continue by using the `tabular` or `longunderstack` methods, or something completely different?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is rather a job for a table or a list

Comment: This is typical thread from tex.sx here. OP don't know how works TeX and he/she is thinking about something like `\tab`. The right answer is: you have to study how TeX breaks lines into paragraph and you will find out that there are many primitive parameters, one of them is `\hangindent`. But the accepted answer is overcomplicated and it breaks the baselineskip grid because the table is encapsulated into a box. Another answer recommends to use a package `hanging` which hides the primitive register from the user. Why? Only for one value setting to the primitive register?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Environment `tabular`

A solution with a simple `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Published by:\quad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    Harry Potter\\
    Jack Sparrow\\
    Frodo Baggins
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with simple tabular]

**Remarks:**

- `[t]` aligns the base line of the first tabular row with the surrounding text.
- `@{}` removes the additional spaces (`\tabcolsep`) around the table column.

The names can be made bold in different ways:

- `\textbf` or `\bfseries` for each name:

  ```
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \bfseries Harry Potter\\
    \bfseries Jack Sparrow\\
    \bfseries Frodo Baggins
  \end{tabular}
  ```
- `\textbf` around the whole `tabular`:

  ```
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    Harry Potter\\
    Jack Sparrow\\
    Frodo Baggins
  \end{tabular}}
  ```
- Package `array` provides `>{...}` to insert stuff at the begin of a column:

  ```
  \usepackage{array}
  ...
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\bfseries}l@{}}
    Harry Potter\\
    Jack Sparrow\\
    Frodo Baggins
  \end{tabular}
  ```

With bold entries:

> [image: Result with bold entries]

### Extended version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \setlength{\defaultaddspace}{\baselineskip}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\quad}>{\bfseries}l}
    Published by:
    &  Harry Potter\\
    &  Jack Sparrow\\
    &  Frodo Baggins\\
    \addlinespace
    Title: & A survey of foo and bar \\
    Subtitle: & Finer points \\
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{If you request any further info, contact:}
    \\
    \addlinespace
    & Gandalf in Middle-earth\\
    & Radagast, the Blue
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Extended tabular version]

## Package `varwidth`

A `minipage` can also be used. However its disadvantage is that the width has to be specified. Package `varwidth` defines an environment `varwidth`, which acts like a `minipage`, but the width is automatically decreased to the needed value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
  Published by:\quad
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
    \bfseries
    Harry Potter\\
    Jack Sparrow\\
    Frodo Baggins
  \end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with varwidth]

## Environment `tabbing`

Closer to the method of the question is environment `tabbing`, which
allows the setting and using of tabulators:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabbing}
    Published by:\quad\=\textbf{Harry Potter}\\
    \>\textbf{Jack Sparrow}\\
    \>\textbf{Frodo Baggins}
  \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with tabbing]

### Extended version

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabbing}
    Published by:\quad\=\textbf{Harry Potter}\\
    \>\textbf{Jack Sparrow}\\
    \>\textbf{Frodo Baggins}\\[\baselineskip]
    Title:\>\textbf{A survey of foo and bar}\\
    Subtitle\>\textbf{Finer points}\\[\baselineskip]
    If you request any further info, contact:\\[\baselineskip]
    \>\textbf{Gandalf in Middle-earth}\\
    \>\textbf{Radagast, the Blue}
  \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Extended tabbing version]

Comment: Thanks for the massive infodump Heiko! I'll definitely bookmark this for future reference. Could you please take a look at my edit?

Comment: Perfect, thats answered everything!

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach using the hanging package which may be simpler

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}

\newlength{\hangwidth}
\newcommand{\newhang}[1]{\settowidth{\hangwidth}{#1}\par\hangpara{\hangwidth}{1}#1}

\begin{document}

\newhang{Published by: }Name 1\\Name 2\\Name 3

\newhang{\textbf{Published by: }}Name 1\\Name 2\\Name 3

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One could use an understack.  EDITED to confirm it works with `\textbf{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\begin{document}
Published by:\hspace{1em}\Longunderstack[l]{%
  \textbf{Name.}\cr
  Longer Name.\cr
  Another Name.}

Next paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Steven, when I do this and add \textbf{Name.} the names don't show up.

Comment: @JimBob It works for me when I do `\textbf{Name.}`.  Is your version of `stackengine` up to date? V3.24, as shown in the log file.

Comment: Hi Steven, don't mind me, I was just being a plonker. Looks like I forgot the final "}".

Answer (score 3):

The `\hangindent` primitive should be used. For example:

```
\def\\{\hfil\break}
\def\indentby#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\noindent \hangindent=\wd0 \box0
                \ignorespaces}

\indentby{Published by: }  Harry Potter\\
                           Jack Sparrow\\
                           Frodo Baggins
\bye
```

Note, that if you are using LaTeX then you needn't to define `\\`.