# formatting thesis keywords

Tags: indentation

I need to format multi-line keywords in this way:

```
Keywords: keyword1  keyword2  keyword3
          keyword4
```

I use a given LaTeX class and the corresponding definition of the keywords environment is:

```
\newcommand\englishkeywords[1]{%
  \vspace{2ex}\noindent{\bf\zihao{-4} \ABCD@label@englishkeywords} \bf\zihao{-4}#1}
```

I try to use `\parbox` to achieve what I want:

```
\newcommand\englishkeywords[1]{%
  \vspace{2ex}\noindent{\bf\zihao{-4} \ABCD@label@englishkeywords} \parbox[t][][t]{0.8\linewidth}{\raggedright\bf\zihao{-4}#1}}
```

The code works almost perfect, but I don't know how to set the `width` (0.8\linewidth here) parameter of the `\parbox`. If I set it to a bigger value, it'll cause underfull or overfull. How can I solve this or is there any better way to format?

**UPDATE:**

Sorry for not describing it clearly, I want to improve the class and I hope to do this in a more versatile way (i.e. it can also deal with the case that there's only one line keywords)

**MWE:**

```
% things related to custom class have been removed
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\def\englishkeywordslabel{Keywords:~}
\newcommand\englishkeywords[1]{%
  \vspace{2ex}\noindent{\bf \englishkeywordslabel} \parbox[t][][t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright\bf#1}}
  %\vspace{2ex}\noindent{\bf englishkeywords} \bf#1}

\begin{document}
I'm a reference line I'm a reference line I'm a reference line I'm a reference line I'm a reference line 

\englishkeywords{keyword1\quad keyword2\quad keyword3\\ keyword4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This recent question looks similar and could help you to solve your case : http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243451/34551

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for the guidance. I've updated my post.

Comment: @Clément Please see my updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list; you'll have no problem with spacing below the parbox.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\englishkeywordslabel{Keywords:}
\newcommand\englishkeywords[1]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{2ex}%
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{\bfseries\englishkeywordslabel~}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{\leftmargin}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}%
  }
  \raggedright\bfseries\item[\bfseries\englishkeywordslabel~]#1
  \end{list}
}
\begin{document}

I'm a reference line I'm a reference line I'm a reference line
I'm a reference line I'm a reference line

\englishkeywords{keyword1\quad keyword2\quad keyword3\\ keyword4}

I'm a reference line I'm a reference line I'm a reference line
I'm a reference line I'm a reference line

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works for you. I'm not entirely certain what your concern is about a one-line keyword list, so let me know if I misunderstood.

Regardless, you can improve on your formatting.  There are two obvious issues: (1) you are using obsolete (for LaTeX) commands like `\bf`; and (2) you could 'modularize' your set up so that it can be easily changed at the document level (assuming the keywords-related commands are set in the `.cls` or `.sty`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% for the sake of the example
\usepackage{etoolbox,xcolor}

\newcounter{countargs}%   count items in the list
\newcounter{iterateargs}% iterate over items in list

\newcommand{\mykeywords}[1]{%
  \bigskip
  \begingroup
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
  \kwlabel\space
  \parbox[t]{0.8\linewidth}{%
      \setcounter{countargs}{0}%
      \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{countargs}}%
      \docsvlist{#1}%
      \setcounter{iterateargs}{0}%
      \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
        \stepcounter{iterateargs}%
        \raggedright
        \printkeyword{##1}%
        \ifnum\value{iterateargs}<\value{countargs}%
        \keywordlistsep\quad   % <-- how to separate list items
        \else\fi
      }%
    \docsvlist{#1}%
  }%
\end{minipage}
\endgroup
\bigskip
}

% These are things that could be easily redefined in the `.tex` files if the above commands are in a `.cls` or `.sty` file...
% Keyword label:
\newcommand{\kwlabel}{{\kwlabelfmt
    Keywords:%
  }}
% Keyword label format:
\newcommand{\kwlabelfmt}{\bfseries\sffamily}
% format how the keywords appear
\newcommand{\printkeyword}[1]{\sffamily #1}
% Separator for list items
\newcommand{\keywordlistsep}{;}
% Note: depending on how much control you want to give to the user, other commands could be factored out and of \mykeywords....


\begin{document}
I'm a reference line I'm a reference line I'm a reference line I'm a reference line I'm a reference line


\mykeywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, }

\renewcommand{\printkeyword}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\mykeywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, {keyword4, with commascommas in it, so it needs to be braced}, keyword 5}

\mykeywords{ Sorry for not describing it clearly{,} I want to improve
  the class and I hope to do this in a more versatile way (i.e. it can
  also deal with the case that there's only one line keywords}

\end{document}
```